# Terminate called without an active exception when returning from a method

Tags: c++, multithreading, terminate

I am making this game and i need to return back to the main method again to start another life of the player. but when i am returning from the method of another class the error comes as terminate called without an active exception.

I have tried looking how to close the thread before returning but most of the solutions i find on internet they just close all the threads including main and so no work i just want to return to the main method. I have replicated my problem in the following code. I think there is a very simple answer to this that i am not able to figure out so please help me out.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<conio.h>
#include<thread>
using namespace std;
class first{
    public:
    int ch;
    void getDir();
    void func();
};
void first::getDir(){
    while(1){
        ch = _getch();
    }
}
void first::func(){
    thread getDirection(&first::getDir,this);
    while(1){
        //do stuff
        while(1){
            //do stuff
            return;
        }
    }
}
int main(){
    while(1){
        first f;
        f.func();
    }
}
```

Comment: `thread getDirection(&first::getDir,this);` went out of scope without being `detach`ed or `join`ed. [See first paragraph of description in this documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread). Lemme see if I can find you a good duplicate.

Comment: if i add getDirection.detach() before returning from func() what will actually happen, will the previous thread be still  in memory and i'll be creating new threads every time or anything else.

Comment: If you `detach`, the thread will still be there (unless it starts and runs to completion very quickly) running in the background until it completes. It's out of C++'s hands at that point and the OS or whatever will take care of things from there. The `thread` object will be out of scope and gone from memory. Where `detach` gets ugly is you've given up all control of the thread. If the thread is still running and possibly doing something important when the program exits, the results can be undesirable.

Comment: My preference is to store the threads and `join` them at the end of the program if they are relatively few in number and have long, well-defined lives. If they come and go quickly handling short tasks in the background, I'll use a [thread pool](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/173575/what-is-a-thread-pool) instead. If I have large numbers of long-lived, well defined threads, I'll probably be wondering where my design went wrong.